# Python script not finding module installed by Github Workflow despite confirmation it's installed

Tags: python, macos, cmake, pip, github-actions

I have a C++ library built using CMake, and it uses data pulled from https://www.dnd5eapi.co/. To do this, I have a Python script that runs and pulls the data using requests.

```py
import os
import json
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pulls = ["backgrounds",
             "classes",
             "equipment-categories/armor",
             "equipment-categories/weapon",
             "races",
             "subclasses"]

    gets = {}

    for item in pulls:
        with requests.get("https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/" + item) as jsonurl:
            gets[item] = jsonurl.json()

    for item in gets:
        if not os.path.exists(item):
            os.makedirs(item)

        with open(item + "/" + item.split("/")[-1] + ".json", "w") as super_f:
            super_f.write(json.dumps(gets[item]))

        for it in gets[item]["equipment" if "equipment" in gets[item] else "results"]:
            if "url" in it:
                with requests.get("https://www.dnd5eapi.co" + it["url"]) as jsonurl:
                    with open(item + "/" + jsonurl.json()["index"] + ".json", "w") as f:
                        f.write(json.dumps(jsonurl.json()))
```

I already have confirmed it runs and grabs the data on more than one machine. To test my library, I use the GitHub CMake Workflow to automatically build and test the code. If the option is specified, I run the Python code from my CMakeLists.txt.

```
option(PULL_DATA "Pull the API data from 5e API" OFF)

if (PULL_DATA)
    find_package(Python REQUIRED)

    if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/apipull.py")
        message("-- Found API Script: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/apipull.py")
        execute_process(COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} apipull.py
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/
                RESULT_VARIABLE outt
                )

        if(NOT ${outt} EQUAL 0)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "-- API Data script did not complete successfully!")
        endif ()

        message("-- Script output: ${outt}")
        message("-- API Script Finished")
    else ()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "-- Cannot find script to pull API data!")
    endif ()

    execute_process(COMMAND pip show requests
            RESULT_VARIABLE ecode
            OUTPUT_QUIET
            )

    if (NOT ${ecode} EQUAL 0)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "-- Cannot find Python module \"requests\". Please install the requirements.txt or set INSTALL_REQ to true.")
    endif ()

    message("-- Found required Python modules")
endif ()
```

This works on my machine, and on the `ubuntu-latest` OS with GitHub Actions. The problem begins when I try to build on `macos-latest` as `requests` isn't automatically installed. To solve this, I set the Python version and installed any dependencies using the `cmake.yml`. The relevant portion is:

```yaml
name: CMake

on: [push]

env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work equally
    # well on Windows or Mac.  You can convert this to a matrix build if you need
    # cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
        python-version: [3.8]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      # Allows us to test a wide range of Python versions
      # This is to ensure full spectrum testing
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2

    - name: Install dependencies
      # This installs our dependencies so it can automatically be built in testing
      # Normally the user would run Python to ensure the data exists
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install requests
```

I've also set it to 3.5-3.8 but nothing works. I've tried different configurations of using pip but nothing happens. I can confirm by viewing the logs that `requests` is installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.0.1
Successfully installed pip-21.1
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi, requests
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Successfully installed certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-4.0.0 idna-2.10 requests-2.25.1 urllib3-1.26.4
```

but I still get

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.4") found components: Interpreter 
-- Found API Script: /Users/runner/work/libeztp/libeztp/data/apipull.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/runner/work/libeztp/libeztp/data/apipull.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (message):
  -- API Data script did not complete successfully!


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/runner/work/libeztp/libeztp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

everytime. Does anyone have any help they can offer as to why this is happening? I'm legitimately confused as I see zero reason why the module isn't being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that on MacOS with GitHub Actions, there are multiple installed python interpreters and CMake wasn't finding the system version. I discovered this by adding `python -m pip list` to my `cmake.yml` before running the configuration for CMake. This gave me the Python location that GitHub Actions was using: `/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.4/x64`, but CMake was finding an interpreter at `/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9`. So I changed the `CMakeLists.txt` from

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} apipull.py
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/
                RESULT_VARIABLE outt
                )
```

to

```
execute_process(COMMAND python apipull.py
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/
                RESULT_VARIABLE outt
                )
```

Everything runs perfectly now!